# Lua require doesn't work on directories

Tags: lua

I have been given some skeleton code for an assignment from my professor in lua. The code has several require statements that add packages to the current directory. The problem I am having is that many of these require statements are not requiring a .lua file, they require a directory containing many lua files. For instance, I have a directory qtwidget with a single file in it: init.lua

In the skeleton code, this package is referenced like this:

```
local w = qtwidget.newwindow(width,height,"Energy surface")
```

So that's all fine and dandy, but when I run the skeleton code I get the following error:

```
dofile('/data/mar608/BigData/src/optim/demo2.lua')
error loading module 'qttorch' from file '/usr/local/pkg/torch/share/torch/lua/qttorch':
cannot read /usr/local/pkg/torch/share/torch/lua/qttorch: Is a directory
stack traceback:
[C]: ?
[C]: in function 'require'
/data/me/BigData/src/optim/demo2.lua:36: in main chunk
[C]: in function 'dofile'
[string "dofile('/data/mar608/BigData/src/optim/demo..."]:1: in main chunk
[C]: ?
```

What's going on? Why doesn't lua understand this require statement? Is there any way I need to chance my package.path variable that will solve this problem? I need to be able to do this for many directories (i.e. specify the directories name and have lua load all it's files into a single name to be referenced later)

Answer (score 3):

1) Do you have `/usr/local/pkg/torch/share/torch/lua/qttorch/init.lua` ?
2) Do you have `.../?/init.lua` entry in `package.path` ?
Example: `/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/?/init.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/?.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/?/init.lua;./?.lua`.